# How to extend scrapy feed export to send crawl results in POST requests - open and store not called?

Tags: python, python-requests, scrapy

I have written a spider and it works fine. I now wish to send the results of that scrape to a rest API via POST request.

I'm under the impression that extending the feed export functionality to have it make POST requests instead of writing to a file/sending it to S3/etc.

I am sure that my settings.py and configuration is correct, but for some reason the `open` and `close` functions are never called, even when I literally copy and paste and rename preexisting feed export classes from feedexport.py.

Please see code below:

`settings.py`

```
EXTENSIONS = {'project.extensions.ExportToApi.ExportScrape':400}
FEED_STORAGES = {'http': 'project.extensions.ExportToApi.ExportScrape'}
FEED_API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'
```

(there's a simpleserver at localhost:8000 there printing out all the GET and POST requests it receives)

`/project/extensions/ExportToApi.py`

```
from scrapy.extensions.feedexport import BlockingFeedStorage

class ExportScrape(BlockingFeedStorage):
    def __init__(self, crawler, uri):
        self.crawler = crawler
        self.url = uri

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        uri_from_settings = crawler.settings['FEED_API_URL']
        return cls(crawler, uri_from_settings)

    def _store_in_thread(self, file):
        file.seek(0)
        import requests
        r = requests.post(self.url, data=file)
        file.close()
```

When added, print statements are run from `__init__` and `from_crawler`, but not `_store_in_thread`, nor `open` or `store` if they are implemented.

Answer (score -1):

POST requests to rest api - is directly the same type of http requests as regular requests scrapy send.
One of options is to.. inside `parse` method return `Request` object with empty callback to rest API endpoint instead of `item` object of `dict` (and withiout any custom feed storages)

```
def parse(self, response)
    ...
    #yield item
    ...
    yield Request(
        method='post',
        url=server_url,
        body=converted_item_data,
        callback=self.not_parse)

def not_parse(self, response):
    pass
```